# How to check if an object exists when passing variables with jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

In Jade you can pass through an object to the client like this

Route:

```
res.render('mypage', {
  title: 'My Page',
  myobject : data
});
```

Jade Template:

```
extends layout

block navbar
  include includes/navbar
block top
  include includes/top
block content
  script(src='/js/controllers/test-controller.js')
  script.
    var clientobj = !{JSON.stringify(myobject)}
```

But what if myobject does not exist? It seems like it would be the simplest thing to check if this object exists before using it (and therefore only try to define the var `clientobj` if it does) but I am banging my head here trying to get make this happen.

Eg:

```
res.render('mypage', {
  title: 'My Page'
});
```

Will currently break the given template, there has to be some syntax to make this code more resilient, surely..

Comment: Why not just check after `clientobj` has been created? If nothing is there, it'll be `undefined`

Comment: why not use jade's if condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet should help.

```
script
    if myobject
        | var clientobj = !{JSON.stringify(myobject)}
```

Please note that you should not put `.` (dot) at the end of `script` element. Otherwise `if myobject ...` will be considered as text and not Jade code.

Alternatively this should work too:

```
script.
    var clientid = #{myobject ? JSON.stringify(myobject) : "undefined"};
```

In that case you will get following HTML code and you will have to handle `clientid` as `undefined` in your JavaScrip code in a page.

```
<script>var clientid = undefined;</script>
```

I hope that will help

Comment: Ah ha. Sigh, I must have tried 5 different variations of conditional statements but all with the check outside the script tag, using jade, not inside like this. Thank you.

Comment: @OliverLloyd, great I could help to solve you problem